# Tengo un out of bounds

Tags: java

tengo esta función en la que devuelvo un jugador que tiene las mejores estadísticas pero cuando elimino un jugador del ArrayList me da out of bounds pero si no los elimino no saca solo 1 jugador, el que mejor estadística tiene.

Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias de antemano

```
 public static String devolverMVP() {
        String ret = "";

        float statsJugador1 = 0;
        float statsJugador2 = 0;

        ArrayList<JugadorNormal> jugadoresNormalesNBA = getTodosLosJugadoresNBA();

        for (byte i = 1; i < jugadoresNormalesNBA.size(); i++) {

            statsJugador1 = jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getAPG() + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getPPG()
                    + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getRBG() + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getSPG()
                    + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getBPG();
            statsJugador2 = jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i - 1).getAPG() + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i - 1).getPPG()
                    + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i - 1).getRBG() + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i - 1).getSPG()
                    + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i - 1).getBPG();

            if (statsJugador2 > statsJugador1) {
                jugadoresNormalesNBA.remove(i);
                ret += "\n" + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i) + "\n";
            } else {
                jugadoresNormalesNBA.remove(i - 1);
                ret += "\n" + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i - 1) + "\n";
            }

        }

        return ret;

    }
```

Comment: Es probable que el error esté en el if. Fíjate que quitas un elemento en la posición `i` y luego intentas acceder al elemento en la misma posición. Lo mismo con `i - 1`. Y si quieres un solo elemento de la lista, no hace falta que le andes quitando elementos.

Comment: Pero es que si remueves un jugador dentro del ciclo está claro que te va a saltar el `out of bounds`. Imagina que empiezas a iterar y al inicio, cuando el `for` se evalúa, tienes 3 elementos. Pero luego remueves 1. Cuando `i = 2` va a explotar, porque ahora el arreglo tiene 2 elementos no 3. **Moraleja**: En un `for`, nunca cambies la longitud del arreglo o lista sobre la que estás iterando.

Answer (score 0):

**¿Qué te ocurre?**
Suponte, que jugadoresNormalesNBA es un ArrayList de tamaño 3.

Al llegar al for, jugadoresNormalesNBA.size() = 3, por lo que hará las iteraciones:
i=1 e i=2. (empezando en 1 y mientras sea menor que 3).

Tienes 3 elementos, el elemento 0,1 y 2 por lo que en la primera iteración, i=1, i-1=0.

En las comparaciones, en función de los valores, eliminas siempre uno de los dos registros.

En la segunda iteración es donde tendrías el problema, i=2 y i-1=1:

- En ésta iteración solo tendrás dos elementos dentro del ArrayList (se quitó uno en la iteración anterior).

**Solución al error, pero no al problema, utilizando el mismo bucle for:**
Almacenar los indices a eliminar y no eliminarlos dentro del mismo bucle for que los itera. Digo que no solucionas el problema, ya que en el caso de tener como elementos:
6 2 4, tal y como lo tienes, tendrás como índices a eliminar sólo el elemento 2, ya que 6>2(2 a eliminar) y 4>2(2 a eliminar).(pruébalo).

**Una posible solución:**
Utiliza una variable máximo y en cada iteración, si el valor del
jugador del indice es mayor que el máximo, dicho valor será el máximo.

```
public static String devolverMVP() { 
      String ret = ""; 

      ArrayList<JugadorNormal> jugadoresNormalesNBA = getTodosLosJugadoresNBA();
      //Comprobar que haya al menos un jugador.
      JugadorNormal max_jugador = jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(0);
      float max = max_jugador.getAPG() + max_jugador.getPPG()
                + max_jugador.getRBG() + max_jugador.getSPG()
                + max_jugador.getBPG();

      for (byte i = 1; i < jugadoresNormalesNBA.size(); i++) {
        
         statsJugador = jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getAPG() + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getPPG()
                + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getRBG() + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getSPG()
                + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getBPG();
            
         if (statsJugador > max) {
            max_jugador = jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i);
            max = statsJugador;
         }    
      }
      ret += "\n" + max_jugador + "\n";
      return ret;

}
```

Comment: Vale con ee código ya ha solucionado mi problema gracias!!!Solo tuve que cambiar el byte del iterador porque el ArrayList contiene 150 elementos pero por el resto,todo perfecto