# Conseguir 10 jugadores

Tags: java, arraylist

estoy intentando hacer un all star para un juego de NBA.Para ello tengo una función en la que le paso el ArrayList de jugadores y lo que intento hacer es que compare todos los jugadores y me saque los 10 que mejores estadísticas tenga pero no sé como enfocarlo bien del todo.Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido pero me he quedado estancado,alguien echa una mano?Gracias

```
public static ArrayList<JugadorAllStar> conseguirJugadoresAllStar() {

    ArrayList<JugadorAllStar> jugadoresAllStar = new ArrayList<JugadorAllStar>();

    ArrayList<JugadorNormal> jugadoresNormalesNBA = getTodosLosJugadoresNBA();

    JugadorNormal max_jugador = jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(0);
    float max = max_jugador.getAPG() + max_jugador.getPPG() + max_jugador.getRBG() + max_jugador.getSPG()
            + max_jugador.getBPG();
    float statsJugador = 0;

    for (short i = 1; i < jugadoresNormalesNBA.size(); i++) {

        statsJugador = jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getAPG() + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getPPG()
                + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getRBG() + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getSPG()
                + jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getBPG();

        if (statsJugador > max) {
            JugadorAllStar j = new JugadorAllStar(jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getNombre(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getApellido(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getDorsal(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getApodo(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getPosicion(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getSalario(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getNominacionesAllStar(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getAnillosDeCampeon(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getMVPs(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getDefensorDelAño(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).isRookieDelAño(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).isMIP(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getMVPAllStar(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getFMVP(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getPremioAnotador(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getPPG(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getAPG(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getRBG(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getSPG(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getBPG(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getMPG(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getfinalizacion(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).gettiro(),
                    jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getorganizacion(), jugadoresNormalesNBA.get(i).getdefensas());
            
            jugadoresAllStar.add(j);
        }
    }

    return jugadoresAllStar;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes prácticamente el mismo código que la respuesta que te di en esta otra pregunta que hiciste:

[Tengo un out of bounds](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/532722/tengo-un-out-of-bounds/532893#532893)

Para lo que consultas, podrías almacenar en un HashMap<puntuacion, JugadorNormal> todos los jugadores con sus puntuaciones, ordenarlos y luego obtener los 10 primeros.
Puedes echarle un vistazo al siguiente enlace:

https://ricardogeek.com/ordenar-un-hashmap-en-java/